How to create a diagonal line within a grid cell?
I'm tring to create a table with a diagonal divider in the first cell, as shown in the following figure.

I tried using a Graphics in the first cell.
Grid[{
  {Graphics[{Line[{{0, 1}, {1, 0}}], Text["Head I", {0.25, 0.25}], 
     Text["Head II", {0.75, 0.75}]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
    ImageSize -> 80], "Second", "Third"},
  {, "foo", "bar"}
  },
 Frame -> All]

Above code will give

However, there is a annoying gap between the endpoints and the grid lines. So I changed the Spacings,
Grid[{
  {Graphics[{Line[{{0, 1}, {1, 0}}], Text["Head I", {0.25, 0.25}], 
     Text["Head II", {0.75, 0.75}]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
    ImageSize -> 80], "Second", "Third"},
  {, "foo", "bar"}
  },
 Frame -> All,
 Spacings -> {{1 -> 0, 2 -> 0}, {1 -> 0, 2 -> 0}}]

But this would cause the second row and second column too close to the grid lines.

So, is there an automatic and elegant way to get a table shown in the first picture?
Note: The foo and bar in the picture are just indicative, what I actually want to place are plots with PlotHighlighting, otherwise I could easily complete this task with other software.
Update: I wrote an anwser that achieved good results by setting the Spacings to zero and manually adding margins using AdjustmentBox. It's good enough for me, but there is still room for improvement. So I still welcome better implementations.

@A.Kato and cvgmt If you check the edit history, you'll find I feel hesitated, too. (Mark as duplicate -> reopen -> mark as duplicate again. ) I finally decide to mark it as duplicate because, I believe if the original question cannot be answered perfectly, then this question cannot be answered, either. If it can be, then answers should be posted under that question rather than this one. Anyway, I won't be against the decision of the community. You guys believe it's not a duplicate and reopen it, that's fine.

@xzczd Oh, I thought someone (not me) could answer this. But expert like you says "cannot be answered perfectly",  this must be a difficult question.... I guess it can't be helped if it's closed. Sorry for bothering you guys.

Related How to make a Slash header in Grid?

@A.Kato I'm not an expert for grid layouts, either :) . I just feel that, if there is an answer for this question, then that answer should also be an answer for the question How to make a Slash header in Grid?, and answering unanswered old question should be encouraged. No need to say sorry!

You could just wrap "Second" and "Third" in a Pane and  then add a ImageMargins option in them. Not great, but better.

Using a previous method
 
 Grid[{{"", "Second", "Third"}, {"", "foo", "bar"}}, 
   Spacings -> {0, 0}, 
   ItemSize -> {{Scaled[.2], Scaled[.15], Scaled[0.15]}, 
                {Scaled[0.05], Scaled[0.05], Scaled[.05]}}, 
   Dividers -> All, 
   Alignment -> {Center, Center}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontWeight -> Bold, 
     FontSize -> 16}] // 
  ReplacePart[{{1, 1, 1} -> 
     Graphics[{Line[{Scaled[{0, 1}], Scaled[{1, 0}]}], 
       Text["Diag Column\nHead II", Scaled[{0.7, 0.7}]], 
       Text["Diag Column\nHead I", Scaled[{0.25, 0.3}]]}, 
       PlotRegion -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
       ImageSize -> {Scaled[1], Scaled[1]}, 
       AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
       ImagePadding -> None, 
       PlotRangePadding -> None, 
       BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontFamily -> Times, 
        FontSize -> 12}]}]


With Plot Examples
foo = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}];
bar = Plot[Nest[Sin, x, 100], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}];

 Grid[{{"", "Sin Plot", "Nested Sin Plot"}, {"", 
     Item[foo, ItemMargins -> 5], Item[bar, ItemMargins -> 5]}}, 
   Spacings -> {0, 0}, 
   ItemSize -> {{Scaled[.2], Scaled[.15], Scaled[0.15]}, 
                {Scaled[0.05], Scaled[0.05], Scaled[.05]}}, 
   Dividers -> All, 
   Alignment -> {Center, Center}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontWeight -> Bold, 
     FontSize -> 18}] // 
  ReplacePart[{{1, 1, 1} -> 
     Graphics[{Line[{Scaled[{0, 1}], Scaled[{1, 0}]}], 
       Text["Diag Column\nHead II", Scaled[{0.7, 0.7}]], 
       Text["Diag Column\nHead I", Scaled[{0.25, 0.3}]]}, 
      PlotRegion -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
      ImageSize -> {Scaled[1], Scaled[1]}, 
      AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
      ImagePadding -> None, 
      PlotRangePadding -> None, 
      BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontFamily -> Times, 
        FontSize -> 12}]}]


Ref
The nested Sin plot example is taken from
Exploring Mathematics with Mathematica

 by Theodore W. Gray and Jerry Glynn ("Theo and Gerry")

 1991, Addison-Wesley


…How do you notice this behavior? How about posting an answer under the linked question to compete for the bounty :) ?

Since you want graphics as output, why not use MaTeX? It also generates graphics, i.e. an image.  It is still inside the notebook so reader does not know if this was Mathematica generated Graphics or image generated by Matex package.  And it is much easier to do in Latex. (and looks better also :)
Using TeXForm, you can also populate this table with Mathematica expressions very easily.
<<MaTeX`
SetOptions[MaTeX,"Preamble"->{"\\usepackage{diagbox}"}]
MaTeX["\\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
\\hline
\\diagbox{Diag\\\\column head I}{Diag Column\\\\Head II} & Second & Third \\\\
\\hline
      & foo & bar \\\\
\\hline
\\end{tabular}
",Magnification->2]



Any plot is OK, at the position of "foo" and "bar".

You can add plots also. Like this
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
p1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -3*Pi, 3*Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray];
p2=Plot[{Sin[x],Sin[2x],Sin[3x]},{x,0,2Pi}];

makePlot[p_Graphics,name_String]:=Module[{r,path},
Export[name<>".pdf",p];
path=FileNameJoin[NotebookDirectory[],name];
path=StringReplace[path,"\\"->"/"];
r="\\includegraphics[width=0.9\\linewidth]{"<>path<>"}"
]

<< MaTeX`
SetOptions[MaTeX, 
  "Preamble" -> {"\\usepackage{diagbox}\\usepackage{graphicx}"}];
MaTeX["\\begin{tabular}{|l|p{1.5in}|p{1.5in}|}
\\hline
\\diagbox{Diag\\\\column head I}{Diag Column\\\\Head II} & Second & \
Third \\\\
\\hline
      &" <> makePlot[p1, "p1"] <> " & " <> makePlot[p2, "p2"] <> " \\\\
\\hline
\\end{tabular}
", Magnification -> 2]



just want the content in the cell to be interactive

Output of MaTeX is just an image (head is Graphics actually).
If you mean you want Dynamics, then I do not see this being possible.
To make changes you'd need to regenerate the whole table again. But you could double click on the output of Matex and do edits. (since it is a Graphics object) just like with any Graphics in Mathematica.
Update
This is the same table given in another answer for illustration
<< MaTeX`
SetOptions[MaTeX, 
  "Preamble" -> {"\\usepackage{diagbox}\\usepackage{caption}"}];
MaTeX["\\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\\hline
\\diagbox{$x:y$}{$\\phi$} & $0$ & $\\frac{\\pi}{4}$ & \
$\\frac{\\pi}{2}$& $\\frac{3 \\pi}{4}$ & $\\pi$ \\\\\\hline
1:1 " <> Table["& aaa", {5}] <> " \\\\\\hline
1:2 " <> Table["& aaa", {5}] <> " \\\\\\hline
1:3 " <> Table["& aaa", {5}] <> " \\\\\\hline
2:3 " <> Table["& aaa", {5}] <> " \\\\\\hline
\\end{tabular}
", Magnification -> 2]



Well, I thought about that. (Actually the first picture in my question is from tex.stackexchange.) But the situation in my question has been simplified. I want to put Plot in the cell, and if you export them as pictures, they will lose the highlighting effect.

@houzw If you show an example of what you want, will try to add it. what plot you want to add and where. Your question has no mention of this.

Any plot is OK, at the position of "foo" and "bar". I just want the content in the cell to be interactive and properly spaced, so you can't convert it to a picture.

Finally, I realized that I can set the Spacings completely to zero and add margins manually using AdjustmentBox.
Clear[firstCell, firstRow, firstColumn, body, margin]
firstCell = 
  Graphics[{Line[{{0, 1}, {1, 0}}], Text["y", {0.25, 0.3}], 
    Text["x", {0.75, 0.7}]}, ImageSize -> {25, 25}];
firstRow = {"c1", "c2", "c3"};
firstColumn = {"r1", "r2"};
body = {{Graphics[{Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]}, ImageSize -> 200], 
    Plot[x^2, {x, -1, 1}, ImageSize -> 200], 
    Plot3D[x^2 y, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 2}, ImageSize -> 200]},
   {Graphics[{Text[
       "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(a\), \(2\)]\)+\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(b\
\), \(2\)]\)=\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(c\), \(2\)]\)", {0, 0}]}, 
     ImageSize -> 200], Slider2D[Dynamic[a]], 
    Dynamic[Plot[a . {x^2, x}, {x, 0, 2}, ImageSize -> 200]]}};
margin[item_] := 
 DisplayForm@AdjustmentBox[item, BoxMargins -> {{1/4, 1/4}, {1, 1}}]
Grid[Transpose@
  Prepend[Transpose@
    Prepend[Map[margin, body, {2}], margin /@ firstRow], 
   Prepend[margin /@ firstColumn, firstCell]], Dividers -> All, 
 Spacings -> {0, 0}]

As shown in the figure, there is no gap between the slash line in the first cell and the grid lines. And the content meets my interactive needs.

